# What is the package in which the Email class resides?

Tags: java, email, jar, package

What is the package in which the Email class resides? I need the jar or the package to be imported to my Java application. Appreciated your help in advance.

Comment: This is extremely undetailed, please provide more details so the community can help you

Comment: Google it. Search "java api email" or something similar. Try at least to help yourself. Do your homework. [And please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for *JavaMail*: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

It's not part of Java SE, you have to download it separately.